# How to SEARCH additional QUERY in datatable server-side

Tags: php, datatables, server-side

I'm using datatables server-side and everything worked as it should. Now i'm trying to **SEARCH** for the data gotten from the **function attrib()** in my code. This adds more information for each row but problem is - its data cannot be searched.

This is understandable because it does not exist within the main **$sql query** used for searching the database. Is there a way around this?

I know this maybe difficult to understand so i'm trying to be as clear as possible. Please, ask for more clarification if you can help. Thanks.

```
$sql = "SELECT  mat_code,mat_descp,short_code_details,approverComment,date_created,
                mt.mat_type, mt.mat_desc,
                vc.val_class,vc.val_class_desc,
                vc.val_cat_code,vc.val_cat_desc,
                n.noun_name,n.qualifier,n.shorttext_item,
                u.uombs,
                mg.mtgp_id,mg.mtgp_desc,
                pt.plant_name,
                sl.sl_id,sl.sto_loc_name,
                pg.pur_id,pg.purchs_gp_name,
                us.fname,us.lname,mat_status
                    FROM mat_master_head mmh
                INNER JOIN material_type mt ON mmh.mat_type = mt.mat_type
                LEFT OUTER JOIN valuation_class vc ON mmh.val_class_id = vc.id
                INNER JOIN noun n ON mmh.noun_id = n.noun_id
                INNER JOIN uom_bs u ON mmh.uombs_id = u.uombs_id
                INNER JOIN material_group mg ON mmh.mg_id = mg.id
                INNER JOIN plant pt ON mmh.plant_id = pt.plant_id
                INNER JOIN storage_location sl ON mmh.sl_id = sl.id
                INNER JOIN purchase_gp  pg ON mmh.pur_id = pg.pur_id
                INNER JOIN users us ON mmh.user_id = us.id
                WHERE (1=1)";
                // AND mat_status = 4 AND (download_status = 0 OR download_status = 1)

if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {   // if there is a search parameter, $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter

    $sql.=" AND ( mat_code LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR plant_name LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR sto_loc_name LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR noun_name LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR qualifier LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR shorttext_item LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR short_code_details LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR uombs LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR mat_descp LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR fname LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR lname LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR date_created LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' )";

}

$query = $conn->query($sql);
$totalFiltered = $query->rowCount(); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result.

if( !empty($requestData['order'][0]['column']) || !empty($requestData['order'][0]['dir']) || !empty($requestData['start']) || !empty($requestData['length'])) {

$sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   

".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']." ";
    $sql.=" LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." , ".$requestData['length']." ";
    /* $requestData['order'][0]['column'] contains colmun index, $requestData['order'][0]['dir'] contains order such as asc/desc  */
    }

    $query = $conn->query($sql);


///Attribute Function//////////////////////////////////

    function attrib($mat_code)
    {
        global $conn;

    $mat_query = "SELECT a.attributes, mmd.attr_value, u.uombs FROM mat_master_details mmd
                    INNER JOIN attribute a ON mmd.attr_id = a.attr_id
                    INNER JOIN uom u ON a.uombs_id = u.uombs_id
                    WHERE mat_code = '$mat_code' AND mmd.attr_value >= '0'";
    $mat = $conn->query($mat_query);

    $attribs = '';

    foreach($mat as $mats){
        $attribs .= removeSlash($mats['attributes'].' - '.$mats['attr_value'].''.$mats['uombs'].' ');
    }
    return '<span class="colortxt3">'.$attribs.'</span>';
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$data = array();
  foreach ($query as $row)  {  // preparing an array
    $nestedData=array(); //new array to display list

    $nestedData[0] =  $row['mat_code'];
    $nestedData[1] =  MatStatus($row['mat_status']);
    $nestedData[2] = '<span class="lgtxt">'.'PLANT:'.' '.'</span>'.'<span class="colortxt">'.$row['plant_name'].'</span>'.' '.
                     '<span class="lgtxt">'.'STORAGE LOCATION:'.' '.'</span>'.'<span class="colortxt">'.$row['sto_loc_name'].'</span>'.' '.'<br>'.

                     '<span class="lgtxt">'.'NOUN:'.' '.'</span>'.'<span class="colortxt">'.$row['noun_name'].'</span>'.' '.
                     '<span class="lgtxt">'.'QUALIFIER:'.' '.'</span>'.'<span class="colortxt">'.$row['qualifier'].'</span>'.' '.

                     '<span class="lgtxt">'.'SHORT TEXT:'.' '.'</span>'.'<span class="colortxt">'.$row['shorttext_item'].''.removeSlash($row['short_code_details']).'</span>'.' '.
                     '<span class="lgtxt">'.'BASE UOM:'.' '.'</span>'.'<span class="colortxt">'.$row['uombs'].'</span>'.' '.'<br>'.

                     '<span class="lgtxt">'.''.'</span>'.'<span class="colortxt4">'.$row['mat_descp'].'</span>'.' '.
                     '<span class="colortxt3">'.attrib($nestedData[0]).'</span>'.' '.'<br>'.
                     '<span class="lgtxt">'.'CREATED BY:'.' '.'</span>'.'<span class="colortxt2">'.$row['fname']." ". $row['lname'].'</span>'.' '.
                     '<span class="lgtxt">'.'DATE CREATED:'.' '.'</span>'.'<span class="colortxt2">'.$row['date_created'].'</span>';
    $nestedData[3] = '<a href="materialMasterForm.php?id='.$row['mat_code'].'" target="_blank" class="nbtn">View</a>';

    $data[] = $nestedData;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not making this easy. First of all 'datatables' could refer to several things. Just 'tables' with 'data', but I guess it is https://datatables.net

There's a function `attrib()` in your code, but what does it do?! Its name doesn't tell me anything and the comment above it says: "Attribute Function", which is not very enlightening. Ok, it executes a query, I see.

So you output a column in your 'datatable' of which the values come from a query and you want to be able to search that value before you select the row for displaying.

A simple solution would be to put the result of `attrib()` in a column of a table you are searching through. This might be against database normalization rules, but then again it will be the fastest and easiest solution. Just keep in might that you need to update the value in that column every time any of the values, which `attrib()` depends upon, changes. So, that makes this solution rather ugly.

The other solution would be to incorporate the query in `attrib()` as a subquery in your main search query. Given that your search query is already quite complex, this might, in the end, create a very sluggish query. It is however the best solution. In its most basic form it would look something like this:

```
$sql .=" OR (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ....) LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
```

To read more about subqueries see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html

I would urge you to write more readable code. Do not use so many abbreviations, what does `uombs` or `mtgp` mean? You are using a higher level language because that makes your code easier to understand, so don't undermine it. Also write comments that are useful, don't use them as seperators in your code.

Comment: Thank you kiko. I understand your irritation. I appreciate the idea of a subquery and give it a try.